# How to improve very poor quality prints on my Ender 3

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting, creality-ender-3

I get very poor quality prints from my Ender 3: The prints are weak, brittle , stringy and contain gaps.

Please help me sort this as I'm new to 3D printing and have no idea what the problem might be!

The prints look like this:
[image: poor quality superman statue]

Comment: It would be helpful to know what are the print parameters (layer height, speed, filament type, hot-end temperature, etc...). On top of that please let us know what have you already tried to fix it.

Comment: To help you [edit] your question, I have added a  (currently) hidden area - remove the $<$ in front and the $>$ in the back and replace the [] with the relevant information and you have a good start!

Comment: generic quality-improving steps, in order of impact:  print at a slower speed. print with a smaller layer height. cut down on any breeze while printing. reduce printer shaking/vibration with weights/braces. reduce spool friction with baby powder or a spool feeder w/bearing. If you do all those, I can almost guarantee it will come out better than pictured. i would also bump up the temp; it looks like your travels are stretching instead of snapping, and the layer adhesion is sub-par.

Comment: little suggestion (no offence of course) - next time it would be the best to try to make a bit better photo... just focused ;)

Comment: How to improve poor photo quality could be a thing too ;-) It's hard to see the droplets (on the chest for example). Lower speed, up temp a bit for starters.

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest to start with something simpler

there are many test objects to print and see the results
please [take a look here](https://www.thingiverse.com/search?q=test%20object)

the idea is to recognise issues (one by one or at least the most basic) and point them and eliminate them directly

looking at your printout i could of course suggest many things
but it would be better to make this process more clear... for you

so you could manage it on your own

to be somehow constructive

i would say there are 3 main issues on the picture you've presented

- HE temperature
- printing speed
- not-so-stiff printer construction (or belt tension)

print test cube and show your results so we can go further